# C++11 list initialization doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, visual-studio-2013, list-initialization

Here are my files
**screen.h**

```
#ifndef SCREEN_H
#define SCREEN_H


class Screen {
public:
    using pos = std::string::size_type;
    Screen() = default;
    Screen(pos ht, pos wd, char c) : height(ht), width(wd), contents(ht*wd, c) {}
    char get() const { return contents[cursor]; }
    char get(pos r, pos c) const;
    Screen &move(pos r, pos c);

private:
    pos cursor = 0;
    pos height = 0, width = 0;
    std::string contents;
};

inline char Screen::get(pos r, pos c) const {
    pos row = r*width;
    return contents[row + c];
}

inline Screen &Screen::move(pos r, pos c) {
    pos row = r*width;
    cursor = row + c;
    return *this;
}


class Window_mgr {
private:
public:
    std::vector<Screen> screens = { Screen(24, 80, ' ') };

};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "screen.h"

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

int main() {
    Window_mgr w;
    w.screens.push_back(Screen(24, 80, ' '));

    std::vector<Screen> screens = { Screen(24, 80, ' ') };
}
```

The problem is in list initialization line inside `Window_mgr class`. Compiler says:

```
"std::vector<Screen,std::allocator<_Ty>>::vector(std::initializer_list<Screen>,const std::allocator<_Ty> &)": 
невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "Screen" в "const std::allocator<_Ty> &" 
d:\users\family\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication\screen\screen.h
```

But the fact is such list initialization runs properly in two of my tryes outside the class (see main.cpp). I thought it was because of `private` modifier, but `public` didn't help very.
So could you suggest me, please, where the real problem is? Thanks!

**UPD** I use MS VS Expess 2013 and CTP 2013 VC++ compiler.

Comment: [Works with Clang.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c447e96af5c71a7a)

Comment: At this point, only gcc and clang support this syntax. This is new in C++11.

Comment: Even CTP 2013 compiler?

Comment: @user2198121, MSVC12 and the 2013 CTP should support list initialization, including for standard containers. I can't recall how well in-class member initialization works, but perhaps not well with list-initialization.

Comment: It works with the 2013 CTP with `std::vector<Screen> screens{std::initializer_list<Screen>{Screen(24, 80, ' ')}};`, which is unfortunately verbose. I wouldn't be surprised if this is already fixed for MSVC13 tbh.

Comment: And is not recomended to use as I know. It's for С support, isn't it? Although it works.

Comment: try `std::vector<Screen> screens { Screen(24, 80, ' ') };`, or maybe `std::vector<Screen> screens = {{ Screen(24, 80, ' ') }};`

Comment: lol, it works! Second. With `=` or not. thx a lot!

Comment: This is a bug in Visual Studio. It often needs double braces (`{{...}}`) in places where none are actually required.

Comment: @Excelcius I think the unnecessary double braces bug might be related to their hackish implementation of uniform initalization, which seems allows curly braces for *any* function call: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/247271563/hack.png